# terminal output to variable (from java to python) - Best coding practices for placing output into RAM instead of writing files

Tags: java, python, subprocess, wrapper

I am wondering what the best course of action would be in order to get a java ".jar" file output into a python variable.
For example,  let's say a user has a complicated java package (that perhaps the user didn't write and doesn't understand) which they can run in the command window / terminal with

`java -jar FileProcessor.jar -i "input.txt" -o "output.txt"`

Is there a manner to call this in python and get the "output.txt" in a variable, similar to this method:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', 'FileProcessor.jar', '-i', 'sample.txt', '-o'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
py_out = proc.stdout.read()
print(py_out)
```

The problem is clearly that the java file looks for the output file `"output.txt"` after `-o`.

Obviously I am open to other ideas, but as I understand my main options are:

1. `subprocess` `call`/`Popen`? using stdout to log the variable
2. Write a wrapper of the java package

Is there a better way to achieve this?  The first method doesn't appear to be working as easily as many examples would show and I have no idea how difficult it would be to write a wrapper around a java package as I have never done so.

Comment: Why not to use a [temporary file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)?

Comment: @chase thanks for accepting the answer, I have edited it to add windows case. I'm interested by which option you have chosen and what is your platform.

Comment: I decided to do the "cheating" method actually of a temporary file for right now, but I will likely play with the other methods later once I have tested this system a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your program `FileProcessor.jar` doesn't have a special case to output to standard output, there's nothing much you can do (but write to a temporary file and read it again, but that's cheating :).

Most nice commands (Unix commands for instance) either dump data to stdout when the `-o` option is omitted, or when `-o` option has `-` value (dash).

if you cannot modify your program you can fool the program into believing it's writing on a file whereas it's writing on the console:

1. Linux/UNIX:

   - get current `tty` with `tty` command. Ex: `/dev/pts/2`
   - pass that to your program
   - read standard output
2. Windows:

   - use `CON` as output file name
   - read standard output